# Adding a timestamp when menu item is clicked

Tags: function, timestamp, menuitem

I am creating a clocking in button for our organisation in google sheets.

When the menu item 'Clock in' (function: "Clockin") is selected, it adds in a new row, and I want it to add in the current timestamp in cell M4, the current time which updates every minute in cell N4 and the datestamp in cell O4.

I have the current time working but not the time stamp or date stamp!

I've tried various other solutions but as I am still quite a novice with scripts I can't work out where I am going wrong! Any added explanation would be fantastic too!

```
function Clockin() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Hours1');
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
 var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
var range = sheet.getRange(4,2,lastRow-5,lastColumn-4);
  //spreadsheet.getActiveRange(range)
  range
  .sort({column: 2, ascending: false});
  sheet.insertRowsAfter(3, 1);

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Hours1');
///sheet.getRange('M4').INSERT TIME HERE in this format "10:08pm" ;///
sheet.getRange('N4').setFormula('=now()-today()');
///sheet.getRange('M4').INSERT DATE HERE in this format "2 Oct 23" ;///
}
```

I have tried various timestamp fuctions which have worked great, but I can work out how to connect it to the function 'Clockin'

Comment: You did not mention language and platform.

Comment: Worked it out! 
**function Clockin() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Hours1');
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
 var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
var range = sheet.getRange(4,2,lastRow-5,lastColumn-4);
  //spreadsheet.getActiveRange(range)
  range
  .sort({column: 2, ascending: false});
  sheet.insertRowsAfter(3, 1);

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Hours1');
sheet.getRange('M4').setValue(new Date());
sheet.getRange('N4').setFormula('=now()');
sheet.getRange('O4').setValue(new Date());
}'**

Comment: @soundflix I updated it! Google sheets

Comment: Cool thanks for sharing! Another good thing is to put your solution as answer, not comment. That’s easier to read.